# Migrating to the New Places SDK Client not work

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement places picker on my Android app , using the new way provided by google : 
here is the full tutorial URL:

**https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration**

but when adding this implementation to gradale:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
```

this error appears:

> error: cannot access zzbck
>   class file for com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbck not found

That mean as I guess , there is a conflict between the above implantation and the FCM library.

Here is my gradle :

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.0.0'
implementation(name:'HERE-sdk', ext:'aar')
implementation project(':base')
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
implementation(
        [group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core', name: 'jackson-annotations', version: '2.4.1'],
)
implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:2.1.1'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.squareup:android-times-square:1.6.5@aar'
implementation 'cat.ereza:customactivityoncrash:1.5.0'
implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
//    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'
implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
implementation 'com.mikhaellopez:circularprogressbar:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.priyankvex:smarttextview:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.github.lespinsideg:panoramagl:0.1.1'
implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.16@aar'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.0'
implementation 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
//    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.1'
implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.1'
implementation 'com.github.darsh2:MultipleImageSelect:v0.0.4'
//    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
//    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
//    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.4.0'
//    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.4.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.8.0'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.0'
//    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.0'
//    implementation 'com.github.aliumujib:Nibo:2.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Can you post your build.grade file please?

Comment: gradale dependencies added please check

Comment: Seems like you've added the compact version as well as the standalone version.
Could you try deleting implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.0.0' and then syncing the gradle file.

Comment: I received this error :

Error: Type com.google.android.gms.internal.zzckc is referenced as an interface from `com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver`.

:'(

Comment: the error not appear when I do the sync , it appears when I run the app

Comment: AS per the docs, you only need to use either of those. Try running your app now. It should work fine.

Comment: no , in the begging I just implement the first one , but this is one of my trails .
it is not the issue I tried to take the sample provided on Githup from google , and add only the firebase implementation and I got the same error too .

Comment: As per the docs, try including compat version if you want to temporarily migrate from play services. Since, we aren't doing so, I would recommend you to remove that dependency. Also, remove   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.0' . Please let me know if it works.

Comment: no luck :( 

error: cannot access zzb
class file for com.google.firebase.iid.zzb not found

Answer (score -1):

According to Google

https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/client-migration#install_the_compatibility_library

> The Place Picker is only supported in the compatibility library, NOT in the new client library. To continue using the Place Picker, you must install the compatibility library. If you have enabled the previous Places SDK for Android service in the console, do NOT disable it! You must also enable the new API services in the console if you're using them.

Add the Places SDK for Android compatibility library to your project

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places-compat:1.1.0'
}
```

**Note**
You can only install either the client library or the compatibility library, NOT both.

Keep it mind that

> IMPORTANT: The Place Picker is deprecated as of January 29, 2019. This feature will be turned off on July 29, 2019, and will no longer be available after that date. To continue using the Place Picker through the deprecation period, do NOT disable the Places SDK for Android service in your Google Cloud Platform project, as doing so will also disable the Place Picker.